# Is there a way to define first item of pagination results?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm setting up a Symfony project displaying paginated blogposts with an admin interface to manage all this stuff. On this admin it is also possible to "highlight" one of those public blogposts so that this highlighted one is displayed at first position only on the first page.

I need the same item count on each page and that is the problem I'm dealing with.

I'm using [PagerFanta](https://github.com/whiteoctober/Pagerfanta) so I created an AbstractRepository with a "paginate" function.

```
protected function paginate(QueryBuilder $qb, $limit = 20, $offset = 0)
{
    if ($limit == 0) {
        throw new \LogicException('$limit must be greater than 0.');
    }

    //Instantiates the pagination object with the result of the query
    $pager = new Pagerfanta(new DoctrineORMAdapter($qb));

    //Sets max data per page
    $pager->setMaxPerPage($limit);

    //Sets the current page
    $pager->setCurrentPage($offset);

    return $pager;
}
```

In my blogpost repository I made a querybuilder to get all public blogpost excluding the highlighted one because I can get it in another way to display it on top of the first page.

```
public function findAllVisible($id, $limit = 3, $offset = 1, $order = 'DESC')
{
    $qb = $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('a')
        ->select('a')
        ->where('a.website = :website')
        ->setParameter('website', 'blog')
        ->andWhere('a.public = :public')
        ->setParameter('public', true)
        ->andWhere('a.id != :id')
        ->setParameter('id', $id)

        ->orderBy('a.dateInsert', $order)
    ;

    return $this->paginate($qb, $limit, $offset);
}
```

So I first tried to change the limit and the offset according to the current page but I logically lost one item between the first and the second page.

Then I tried to include the highlighted blogpost in querybuilder but I don't know how to define it as the first result if the current page is the first one.

Any idea of how to force the first result to be the highlighted blogpost only on first page? Or another clean and appropriate way to display results as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer to myself because I managed to do what I needed to. In case of someone is dealing with the same issue, here is how I did.

I don't use PagerFanta anymore but Doctrine [Paginator](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/tutorials/pagination.html) tool.
Instead of excluding my highlighted article from my query I replaced my initial `ORDER BY` by `a.id = :highlightedId DESC, a.dateInsert DESC`.
Now it's working as expected.

Here is my new repository function:

```
/**
 * Finds all visible articles
 *
 * @param int $highlightedTipId the highlighted tip id
 * @param int $page current page
 * @param int $limit max items per page
 *
 * @throws InvalidArgumentException
 * @throws NotFoundHttpException
 *
 * @return Paginator
 */
public function findAllVisible($highlightedTipId, $limit = 3, $page)
{
    if (!is_numeric($page)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('$page value is incorrect (' . $page . ').');
    }

    if ($page < 1) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('Page not found');
    }

    if (!is_numeric($limit)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('$limit value is incorrect (' . $limit . ').');
    }

    $entityManager = $this->getEntityManager();

    $query = $entityManager->createQuery(
        "SELECT
            a,
            CASE WHEN a.id = :id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS HIDDEN sortCondition
        FROM App\Entity\Item a
        WHERE
           a INSTANCE OF App\Entity\TipArticle
        AND
            a.website = :website
        AND
            a.public = :public
        ORDER BY
            sortCondition DESC,
            a.dateInsert DESC
        "
    );

    $query->setParameter(':website', 'blog');
    $query->setParameter(':public', true);
    $query->setParameter(':id', $highlightedTipId);

    $firstResult = ($page - 1) * $limit;
    $query
       ->setFirstResult($firstResult)
       ->setMaxResults($limit);
    $paginator = new Paginator($query);

    if (($paginator->count() <= $firstResult) && $page != 1) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('Page not found');
    }

    return $paginator;
}
```

A word about this line `CASE WHEN a.id = :id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS HIDDEN sortCondition`: it is the only way I found to do a `ORDER BY a.id = :highlightedId DESC` with Doctrine. As you can see I made a DQL but I is also possible with QueryBuilder.

Hope it will help! :)

Comment: Good on you for figuring it out. Could you also post the code that is your answer? Just a change of paginator doesn't really cover it on a code Q&A site ;-) Thanks

Comment: Hi, posted some comments but removed them in favor of an answer. Feel free to use it if you'd like. I thought your answer fairly messy as your mixing up "normal" locations. E.g., you should not need to use the EntityManager in a Repo and you really should not manually build queries (both the QueryBuilder and Criteria are provided to take care of that). So thought I'd provide you with my answer. Keep at it though ;-)

Answer (score 0):

[Nice, well done](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54495814/1155833). If I may offer some advice though. In a repo you shouldn't need to get the ObjectManager (`$this->getEntityManager()`) as the repo is already **for a type of Entity**, `Item` in this case. You should use [Criteria](https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/collections/latest/Doctrine/Common/Collections/Criteria.html) instead. [practical example docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections)

You should have the ObjectManager in whichever controller you've got, so then you'd do:

```
$items = $this-getObjectManager()->getRepository(Item::class)->findAllVisible($params)
```

For use of the Paginator you should use the [QueryBuilder](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/query-builder.html#the-querybuilder), with Expressions, [like here](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/query-builder.html#working-with-querybuilder)

As a practical example, an indexAction of mine:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder;
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator as OrmPaginator;
use DoctrineORMModule\Paginator\Adapter\DoctrinePaginator as OrmAdapter;
use Zend\Paginator\Paginator;

public function indexAction()
{
    // get current page, defaults to 1
    $page           = $this->params()->fromQuery('page', 1);
    // get current page size, defaults to 10
    $pageSize       = $this->params()->fromQuery('pageSize', 10);
    // get ordering, defaults to 'createdAt'
    $orderBy        = $this->params()->fromQuery('orderBy', 'createdAt');
    // get order direction, defaults to Criteria::DESC
    $orderDirection = ($this->params()->fromQuery('orderDirection') === Criteria::ASC)
        ? Criteria::ASC
        : Criteria::DESC;

    $criteria = new Criteria();
    $criteria->setFirstResult($page * $pageSize);
    $criteria->setMaxResults($pageSize);
    $criteria->orderBy([$orderBy => $orderDirection]);

    /** @var QueryBuilder $queryBuilder */
    $queryBuilder = $this->getObjectManager()->createQueryBuilder();
    $queryBuilder->select('a')->from(Article::class, 'a');
    $queryBuilder->addCriteria($criteria);

    $paginator = new Paginator(new OrmAdapter(new OrmPaginator($queryBuilder)));
    $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page);     // set current page
    $paginator->setItemCountPerPage($pageSize);  // set item count per page

    return [
        'paginator' => $paginator,
        'queryParams' => $this->params()->fromQuery(), // pass these for your pagination uri's
    ];
}
```

NOTE: In the above the `$this` is an instance of a Zend Framework controller, where `->fromQuery` returns (if present) a given key from the Query bit if a URI, else return the 2nd param default (or `null`). You should do something similar.